# How to delete a folded XML node (and all child nodes) in NotePad++

Tags: notepad++, xml, code-folding

In the XML example below, lines 8-13 are folded.
Is there a quick way to delete lines 8-13 when folded?

If I select and delete line 8, then lines 9-13 are still there, and the only way I know to get them back is to close and reopen.

This is a small example, but it could be very useful if there were 100s of lines folded.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, there're no ways to delete folded lines.

Comment: Neal - Why not just select the entire "collapsed" folded line with it folded and then just press `Del`? Of course there will be keyboard shortcuts for this too but the line has to be collapsed from what I was able to tell. Otherwise, if you want an automated way with many many lines that will not be a manual thing, you'd need to determine data/XML standards and then based on the standards see if there's a way to complete what you need. Sounds like you are looking for a simple way which you'll do manually though. For the manual way the provided answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short story:

1. Click into the folded line
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Pos1</kbd> or aka <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>
5. <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

or in other words (for mouse users):

1. select the full folded line from start to end.
2. add one more right arrow press to add to the selection.
3. delete the entire folded section with a Delete key press.

Perhaps you may want to record a macro that does the keyboard equivalent actions to select the same text, and bind it to a keycombo for speed's sake.

Please note a triple-click is not working here in the expected way. This is Scintilla functionality rather than Notepad++ functionality. For further information see issue: [Remove XML folded section with triple click](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/4615)

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mark answer.  Deleted my above response, it was the Shift-RightArrow that was new to me.

Comment: Alll the best for you and stay healthy.